# What does "rally behind one another" mean?

Tags: meaning

Can someone explain to me what this expression means? Also if possible, how can I translate it to a Romantic language, such as Spanish?

Below are some sentences that make use of this expression:

> - They *rally behind one another* to rebuild and help one another.
> - We must all *rally behind one another* to keep fighting The Good Fight.
> - Co-workers are more like family, and we all *rally behind one another*
>     to achieve a common goal.

Comment: Hello, John. I've close-voted because this expression is explained quite clearly at [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/rally). The translation request is totally off-topic here.

Comment: @Mysti Quotes must be attributed. Is this from  AHDEL, Collins ...?

Comment: "rally behind one another" : to draw or call together for a common action or effort. (TFD)

Answer (score 6):

The literal definition of *[rally](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rally)* welcomes application to any metaphorical battle:

> verb (rallies, rallying, rallied)
>
> [NO OBJECT]
>   1.0 (Of troops) come together again in order to continue fighting after a defeat or dispersion:
>   *De Montfort’s troops rallied and drove back the king’s infantry*
>
> 1.1 [WITH OBJECT] Bring together (forces) again in order to continue fighting:
>   *the king escaped to Perth to rally his own forces*
>
> 1.2 Assemble in a mass meeting:
>   *up to 50,000 people rallied in the city centre*
>
> 1.3 Bring or come together in order to support a person or cause:
>   [NO OBJECT, WITH INFINITIVE]: *colleagues rallied round to help Ann*
>   [WITH OBJECT]: *a series of meetings to rally support for the union*

In the expressions *[rally around](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rally)*, *[rally to](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rally+to)* or *rally behind*, the object of the preposition indicates a **location** to gather. The reciprocal ***one another*** tends to diffuse the local meaning of the expression *rally behind one another*, but it suggests that in any particular crisis of the metaphoric battle:

> ***everyone*** assembles behind the one who is currently under attack to support them.

Answer (score 4):

When a group of people **rally behind** someone, it  means they are uniting and cooperating to provide support to and solidarity with that person.

If people **rally behind one another**, it means they are uniting for a common purpose.

Answer (score 1):

"Rally" comes to us from the French, to re-ally, thus to regroup for a purpose or to renew an effort.

You can do this by yourself when you **rally from** the depths of illness.

You can **rally with** another person, particularly in boxing or tennis.
Or you can rally with a group, particularly if you're in a automobile driving contest.

You can do this in a group in support of another, whom you **rally around** or **to** or **behind**.  If it's a position or cause that's important, you can **rally for** or **against**.  In this sense, there's a leader (literal or figurative) who gains the support of the crowd lending that support, so it's a little odd for the crowd to rally behind one another because they are both the supporters and the supported.

But the meaning of mutual support is clear.